# calling generic method into other method

Tags: community, salesforce-id

I have written two generic methods for custom approval process now i want call two generic methods into normal methods here is my code and i am facing problem when passing Approve or Reject values into setActionmethod please post solution this is my code

```
/*************************************************************************************
Name            : ApprovalProcessEngine
Created By      : 
Created Date    : ------------
Usage           : The purpose of below code is to submit/approve/reject the record using Apex.
Note            : Befor implementing this code, need to make sure that the Approval Process is already been created and is Active in the system. 


Code Update History:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Date            Last Modified By        Comments/Reason to update
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
************************************************************************************/

public Class ApprovalProcessEngine{

    public ApprovalProcessEngine() {

    }
    public ApprovalProcessEngine(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }
 public static string submitRec(Id recordId){                   

        String subResult = 'FAILED';        //Result return by method to controller

        //create a new approval request to submit
        Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest subReq = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
        subReq.setComments ('Record is submitted for Approval.');
        subReq.setObjectId(recordId);

        //Submit the record for Processing. Use Try-Catch block to handle exception (if any).
        try{
            Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.Process(subReq);

            // To check whether the record gets submitted for Approval or not
            System.debug('Record '+recordId+' got Submitted for Approval');
            subResult = 'SUCCESS';      //Record Submitted Successfully.

        }catch(DMLException e){
            //We can add any message which we want to display on record in case of an Exception appears while saving the record. 
            System.debug('Record failed to Submit for Approval. Reason: '+ e);          
        }                
        return subResult;
    }//End of SubmitRec() method

   public static String approveRejectRec(Id recordId, String action, String Comment){

        String appRejResult = 'FAILED';

        //To Get the 'ProcessInstance' of the records which is 'Pending' in approval Process.
        List<ProcessInstance> proInst = new List<ProcessInstance>([SELECT Id FROM ProcessInstance 
                                                            WHERE TargetObjectId = :recordId 
                                                            AND Status='Pending']);

        if((proInst != null) && (proInst.size() > 0)){

            //Fetching 'ProcessInstanceWorkItem' Id
            List<ProcessInstanceWorkItem> piw = new List<ProcessInstanceWorkItem>([SELECT Id 
                                                            FROM ProcessInstanceWorkItem 
                                                            WHERE ProcessInstanceId =:proInst[0].Id]);    

            //Use for Processing an Approval Request after it is Submitted
            Approval.ProcessWorkItemRequest req2 = new Approval.ProcessWorkItemRequest();
            req2.setComments(Comment);
            req2.setAction(action);
            req2.setWorkItemId(piw[0].id);

            //Use Try-Catch Block to Handle Exception (if any).
             try{    
                // To Capture the Result of Approval Process.
                Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.Process(req2);                
                appRejResult = 'SUCCESS';

            }catch(DMLException e){            
                system.debug('Fail to '+action+'. Reason: '+e);             
            }
        }
        return appRejResult;
    }//End of approveRejectRec() Method.

    public pagereference Submit(){

      string id=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
       submitRec(id);
       return null;
    }
    public pagereference Approve(){
    Approval.ProcessWorkItemRequest req2 = new Approval.ProcessWorkItemRequest();

   //  string app=req2.setAction('Approve');
      string id=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
      string co='failure';
      string ap='approve'; // How pass approve value into setaction method
      approveRejectRec(id,co);
      return null;
    }

     public pagereference Reject(){
     Approval.ProcessWorkItemRequest req2 = new Approval.ProcessWorkItemRequest();

    // string rej=req2.setAction('Reject');
      string id=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
      string co='success';
      string ap='reject'; // How pass reject value into setaction method
     approveRejectRec(id,co);
      return null;
    }
}//End of Class
```

Comment: Please, could you describe your problem (error)?

Answer (score 1):

You've set both of your methods that you seem to be concerned about as pagereferences with return values of null as below:

```
    public pagereference Approve(){
    Approval.ProcessWorkItemRequest req2 = new Approval.ProcessWorkItemRequest();

   //  string app=req2.setAction('Approve');
      string id=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
      string co='failure';
      string ap='approve'; // How pass approve value into setaction method
      approveRejectRec(id,co);
      return null;
    }

     public pagereference Reject(){
     Approval.ProcessWorkItemRequest req2 = new Approval.ProcessWorkItemRequest();

    // string rej=req2.setAction('Reject');
      string id=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
      string co='success';
      string ap='reject'; // How pass reject value into setaction method
     approveRejectRec(id,co);
      return null;
    }
```

There are several ways of returning these values to your page. One is by declaring `string co` as:

```
public co {get;set;}
```

Then create two other methods, one called `getco()` and another called `setco()` that would look like:

```
public string getco()
{
   return co;
}

public void setco(string co)
{
   co = this.co;
}
```

You could then use `getco();` retrieve it's value and `setco('failure');` or `setco('reject);` to set it's value and pass it into another method. Additionally, rather than making your Approve and Reject methods pagereferences, you could make them void methods since you're not returning anything. As I said, there are many possibilities. It greatly depends on how you want to use them with your pages.